# XQuery : why won't my request within many XML files work?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have 2 XML files, the first one contains meteorological measures and the second one locations data :

measures.xml

```
<measure latitude="45.90298482482" longitude="8.92092094">
   ...
</measure>
<measure latitude="45.29848284" longitude="8.72474724">
   ...
</measure>
...
```

locations.xml

```
<location latlng="45.9029,8.9209">
    <address>8, Denver Road</address>
    <place>Goodcity</place>
</location>
<location latlng="45.2984,8.7247">
    <address>3, New Avenue</address>
    <place>Goodcity</place>
</location>
```

So what I want to do is the following : store all the latlngs of a given place, then try to get the measures corresponding to it by using substrings. Here is what I tried, but keeps returning 0 :

```
for $l in //location
where $l/place/string() = 'Goodcity'
return
let $test := $l/@latlng/string() 
return
for $m in //measure
where concat(substring($m/@latitude/string(),0,8),',',substring($m/@longitude/string(),0,7)) = $test
return $m
```

Any idea?

EDIT : the problem doesn't come from the fact I use `susbtring(lat,0,8)` and `substring(long,0,7)`, I know my locations file and these will always return numbers with 4 decimals.

EDIT 2 : finally **it works**, though my request is really long, do you think there is a way to simplify it?

Comment: You need to improve the quality of your questions: 1. Both of the "XML files" contain non-well-formed XML documents. 2. Your code isn't indented and is difficult to read. 3. You have an obvious error in using the `substring()` function. XPath is 1-based, not 0-based. 4. Nowhere have you provided the exact wanted result.  Please, *edit* the question and improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are two separate XML documents then I would expect to see something like

```
for $l in doc('location.xml')//location...

for $m in doc('measures.xml')//measure...
```

Your comparison using substring() seems very error-prone. Why is 45.90298482482 rounded to 45.9029 and not to 45.9030? But I guess you know your own data better than we do.